# How can I view a UDP multicast video stream while away from my home network through OpenVPN?

Tags: stream, udp, video-streaming, gstreamer, vpn

I have a GStreamer pipeline running on a Raspberry Pi on my home's LAN that is multicasting a UDP video (h264) and audio (opus) stream.

```bash
MULTICAST_IP_ADDR=224.1.1.1
VIDEO_UDP_PORT=5001
AUDIO_UDP_PORT=5002

gst-launch-1.0 -v rpicamsrc vflip=true hflip=true \
           name=src preview=0 fullscreen=0 bitrate=10000000 \
           annotation-mode=time annotation-text-size=20 \
           ! video/x-h264,width=960,height=540,framerate=24/1 \
           ! h264parse \
           ! rtph264pay config-interval=1 pt=96 \
           ! queue max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 \
           ! udpsink host=$MULTICAST_IP_ADDR auto-multicast=true port=$VIDEO_UDP_PORT \
           alsasrc device=plug:dsnooped provide-clock=false \
           ! audio/x-raw,rate=44100 \
           ! audiorate \
           ! audioconvert \
           ! audioresample \
           ! opusenc \
           ! rtpopuspay \
           ! queue max-size-bytes=0 max-size-buffers=0 \
           ! udpsink host=$MULTICAST_IP_ADDR auto-multicast=true port=$AUDIO_UDP_PORT
```

I have verified that the multicast is working and is accessible to the devices on the LAN.

I also have an OpenVPN server configured through my router that allows me to access my home network while I'm away.

I realized today that, for some networking reason that i don't yet understand, I'm not able to access the multicast stream (e.g. udp://@224.1.1.1:5001) through my OpenVPN connection like I can when im directly connected to the LAN.

Can you help me find a way to view this stream while connected through OpenVPN?

###### Best case scenario:

- We could access the combined video+audio while we are away (latency is not an issue)

###### Still okay:

- Access to low frame-rate sample of the video stream (maybe 1 or 2 fps)

###### Some initial thoughts

- I can add a Raspberry Pi to act as some kind of intermediary server
- There's a NAS running Home Assistant in Docker, so I could somehow integrate the local stream there?

Any suggestions and ideas are greatly appreciated, let me know if any other details about my set up would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A nice solution was to use HTTP Live Streaming (HLS). On the same Raspberry Pi that is running the multicast video / audio I've done two things:

1. Set up a new receiving pipeline with GStreamer that receives the H264 video / Opus audio and outputs an HLS feed to the disk:

```
sudo rm /var/www/picam-viewer/hls/*.ts
sudo rm /var/www/picam-viewer/hls/*.m3u8

VIDEO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)video,clock-rate=(int)90000,encoding-name=(string)H264,payload=(int)96"
AUDIO_CAPS="application/x-rtp,media=(string)audio,clock-rate=(int)48000,encoding-name=(string)OPUS"

sudo gst-launch-1.0 -v udpsrc address=224.1.1.1 port=5002 caps=$AUDIO_CAPS  \
        ! rtpopusdepay \
        ! opusdec \
        ! audioconvert \
        ! avenc_aac \
        ! queue \
        ! combine_to_hls.audio \
        udpsrc address=224.1.1.1 port=5001 caps=$VIDEO_CAPS \
        ! rtph264depay \
        ! h264parse \
        ! queue \
        ! hlssink2 location="/var/www/picam-viewer/hls/%06d.ts" playlist-location="/var/www/picam-viewer/hls/list.m3u8" max-files=5 playlist-length=3 target-duration=2 name=combine_to_hls
```

2. Set up an Nginx site that facilitates the transfer of the HLS content to the browser using a slightly modified version of this [Picam Viewer project](https://github.com/kamranayub/picam-viewer).

So far this works very well while away from the house over an OpenVPN connection. I did have to reach out to my ISP to request a public IP address for the VPN to work. Thankfully my ISP is not evil and was very helpful with this request (local municipal ISP).